# Break Error in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, break

So I'm trying to remove a 2000hz sine wave from an audio file in C and this is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI (4*atan(1))

int main( void)
{
   int s;
   double d1, newsound, t, i;
   for ( i=0; i>=0; ++i);
      {
         s=scanf( "%lf", &d1);
         if (s != 1) break;
         t=i/8000;
         newsound = d1-sin(2*PI*2000*t);
         printf( "%g\n", newsound);
      }
return 0;
}
```

i keep getting an error that says:
error: break statement not within loop or switch

Comment: Remove the semicolon after `for` statement

Answer (score 0):

This loop has an empty body

```
  for ( i=0; i>=0; ++i); // mind the semicolon
```

the following braces start a "floating" block

```
{ /* floating block */ }
```